# choosing a next point in boundary

Tags: c#

I'm trying to apply bound hall algorithm on set of points which are deployed randomly.
I based on the angle between the previous point and the neighborhood points of the current point to choose the next point with minimal angel. 
What i'm asking for is in some cases the boundary stop generating any point and I've actually debugged the code many times and couldn't figure out what the problem.

The pic of case and the code are given below.

[image]

```
 ArrayList angles = new ArrayList();
                for (int s = 0; s < node.SensorNeighbors.Count; s++)
                {
                    Node n = node.SensorNeighbors[s];


                        if (backboneNodes.Count != 1) // backboneNode is array hase nodes in boundary 
                        {
                           Node previous = backboneNodes[backboneNodes.Count - 2];
                            Double Angle = Math.Atan2(previous.y - node.y, previous.x - node.x) - Math.Atan2(n.y - node.y, n.x - node.x);
                            angles.Add(Angle);

                        }
                        if (backboneNodes.Count == 1)
                        {
                            Double Angle = Math.Atan2(520 - node.y, node.x - node.x) - Math.Atan2(n.y - node.y, n.x - node.x);
                            angles.Add(Angle);
                        }

                }


                int index = 0;
                double minAngle = int.MaxValue;

                for (int s = 0; s < angles.Count; s++)
                {
                    if ((double)angles[s] < minAngle)
                    {
                        minAngle = (double)angles[s];
                        index = angles.IndexOf(minAngle);
                    }



                }

                Node Nnode = node.SensorNeighbors[index];
                int iRadius = (int)Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(node.x - Nnode.x, 2) + Math.Pow(node.y - Nnode.y, 2));
                node.aConnections.Add(node, Nnode, (int)(fTransmissionCost * iRadius / iTransmissionRadius), iReceiveCost, iTransmitterDelay);
                node = Nnode;
```